# specify required version of a package in cmake when the package isn't actually required

Tags: cmake

When I write a `PACKAGEConfig.cmake` file, is there a way to specify that if a specific other package is included, it should be of minimal version?

longer version:
I have a package Foo, and I write a `FooConfig.cmake`. And there is a package Bar, that exists in many versions.

If a third party would

1. use Foo in their project, they use `find_package(Foo)` and everything is fine.
2. use Bar in their project, they use `find_package(Bar)` and everything is fine.
3. use Foo and Bar the mess begins. My current understanding of the compilations is that for reasons out of my control, Foo doesn't work together with Bar in an old version (just `#include "foo.h"; #include "bar.h"` causes compiler errors). Newer versions of Bar are fine. Such that everything is fine if third parties do `find_package(Foo); find_package(Bar 2.0)`.

What's the best way to address this? A hacked solution is to fake a dependency and add `find_package(Bar 2.0)` to `FooConfig.cmake`. Though I don't like that, as this would break use case 1 if Bar is not available.

I guess I could add `if(Bar_FOUND)` to `FooConfig.cmake` and then cause a failure if the Bar version is too low. (Ideally with helpful error messages) but I don't know if that only works if `find_package(Foo)` and `find_package(Bar)` are in the "correct" order in the third party project.

(concrete example is I added [this range-v3 addition](https://github.com/tamaskenez/range-v3/commit/875065c5b5cc90bfcce1f9274c333484b4dada68) to create a `range-v3-config.cmake`, and tried to use range-v3 then in another project, which included boost. This configured well but failed at build time because I picked up boost 1.53, which is apparently too old to work with range-v3 because of colliding `range_mutable_iterator` definitions)

Comment: Do you mean the FooConfigVersion.cmake file? A package can provide information if it is compatible with a requested version or not. See https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Tutorials/How_to_create_a_ProjectConfig.cmake_file for further details.

Comment: Assuming `find_package(Foo)` is called first and you have no control over `Bar` package as it is developed not by you, there is no "official" ways to affect on `find_package(Bar)` call. From my point of view, **documenting** that `Foo` package is incompatible with `Bar` of specific versions is sufficient.

Comment: @vre I was thinking about the `FooConfig.cmake` file. Though I'm new to writing those, so if addressing the issue in `FooConfigVersion.cmake` makes more sense, then that's fine, too.